# Converting .htaccess to nginx. Rewrite not working as it should

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, .htaccess, rewrite, httpd

I can't convert .htaccess to nginx config. I have been trying to use online convert tools. .htaccess to convert is following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?params=$1 [NC]
```

I have been trying to use following nginx config.:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php/?params=$1;
}
```

This is just not working as it should. Also it gives access to other files in this directory. I want only index.php to be available. And even that needs to be working with .htaccess rules.

Installing apache/httpd is not possible on production server.  And I don't want waste resources to run apache inside docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache, you have these `RewriteCond` directives for excluding `!/public` and `/index.php`. In Nginx, just add a separate [`location`s](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for them:

```
location /public {
}
location = /index.php {
}
```

Your [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) is almost there, but unlike in Apache, the *replacement* string in Nginx is always root relative (not `location` relative) and should have the leading `/`. Also, I suggest removing the slash between `php/?` as unnecessary.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?params=$1;
}
```

Comment: Kiitoksia! / Thank you!  I expect this will work also in public folder like:

location /public/assets {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?params=$1;
}

I have "another" file there and it needs rewrite also.

Comment: Remember the root-relativity of _replacement_. If you have another `index.php` in `/public/assets`, you need: `rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/assets/index.php?params=$1;`

Comment: Do you have any idea, why server is now returning php code as download. It will force download index.php contents. 

Current Configuration:
https://pastebin.com/4PJtgUfA

Comment: The `location = /index.php` overrides settings in `location ~ \.php$`. You may remove it as unnecessary. Also read about the [processing order](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration).